# Circular motion and ratios

Tags: geometry

I am trying to get clear in my mind the factors involved in circular motion. I know the formula for centripetal acceleration, and I am aware of the proofs, but I want to understand it simply in terms of the motions involved.
[image]

If I move from B to K along an arc, this is the same as moving from B to H, and from H to K, in the same amount of time.

For a given length B to H, the absolute value of H to K depends on the radius. It is an increasing ratio as the radius gets larger, but the rate of increase is constant.

For a given radius, the ratio of H to K, in relation to B to H, depends on the size of B to H. It is an increasing ratio, but the rate of increase is constant.

The rate of increase (of H to K in relation to B to H) is a constant for the value of a circle. The ratio of increase (of H to K in relation to the radius) is also a constant for the value of a circle.

Therefore the length of H-K is a function of: the radius; the length B-H; and a constant for the rate of curvature of a circle.

Can you help me to define H-K in terms of those three parameters?

Comment: This is strictly a geometry problem due to the absence of any form of force or acceleration. I recommend that it be transferred to the math stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this relates to physics because you're trying to "intuitively derive" the acceleration of a body undergoing uniform circular motion. Finding KH as a function of the radius and the angle between AB and AH would be half the battle. The other half is finding HB at all the same points. Then your tangential velocity would essentially be $KH \hat{x} + HB \hat{y}$. I'm going on my intuition here for the kinds of questions that students ask -- your question is fairly unclear though...

At any rate, to find KH, just note that $AB = FK + KH$. Also, $AB$ is the radius, so let's call it $R$. Solve for $KH$ because that's what you want:

$KH = R - FK$

Now, you need an angle. I think that's what "a constant for the rate of curvature of a circle" meant anyways!Draw a line between $A$ and $K$. Now the angle between $AK$ and $AB$ is what I'll call $\theta$. Since opposite interior angles are equal, $\theta$ is the angle between $AK$, and $FK$. By simple trig then,

$\cos(\theta) = FK/R \,\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,\,FK = R \cos(\theta) $.

And there you have it:

$KH = R - R\cos(\theta).$

Similarly, you can show that $BH = R- R\sin(\theta)$.

Now finally, if you're interested in centripetal acceleration, this is essentially just the change in this velocity vector as you increase $\theta$. Note that if you subtract subsequent time steps of this velocity vector, you get a centripetal acceleration that always points inwards.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, it does indeed help. It seems to me that the circular motion is represented by those two vectors, HK and BH, when they are defined as you have them with cos and sin, but I am not yet able to see how they relate to the centripetal motion, if they do at all.

Comment: they are simply the components of the velocity vector